# ggplot using purrr map() to plot same x with multiple y's

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, purrr

I want to create multiple plots that have the same x but different y's using purrr package methodology. That is, I would like to use the map() or walk() functions to perform this.

Using mtcars dataset for simplicity.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) + geom_point()
```

**edit**
So far I have tried

```
y <- list("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
mtcars %>% map(y, ggplot(., aes(hp, y)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I had tried creating a list of my y variables`y <- list("mpg", "cyl", "disp")` and using that as my .x argument in map(). For the .f argument. I used `ggplot(data = ., aes(x = hp, y = y)) + geom_point()`. Note that I had started by piping in the map function from mtcars so that I call the data with `.` I learned from the answer below (Thanks to MrFlick) is that aes_string() function can be used for the calls to your aesthetics.I also wasn't clear on how to use an anonymous function, or a formula in order to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 8):

This is one possibility

```
ys <- c("mpg","cyl","disp")
ys %>% map(function(y) 
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp)) + geom_point(aes_string(y=y)))
```

It's just like any other map function, you just need to configure your aesthetics properly in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've made a bit more general function for this, because it's part of EDA protocol ([Zuur et al., 2010](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2009.00001.x)). This [article from Ariel Muldoon](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/) helped me.

```R
plotlist <- function(data, resp, efflist) {
  require(ggplot2)
  require(purrr)
  y <- enquo(resp)

  map(efflist, function(x)
    ggplot(data, aes(!!sym(x), !!y)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.25, color = "darkgreen") +
    ylab(NULL)
  )
}
```

where:

- **data** is your dataframe
- **resp** is response variable
- **efflist** is a char of effects (independent variables)

Of course, you may change the geom and/or aesthetics as it needs. The function returns a list of plots which you can pass to e.g. [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) or [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) as in example:

```R
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr) # just for pipes

plotlist(mtcars, hp, c("mpg","cyl","disp")) %>%
 grid.arrange(grobs = ., left = "HP")
```

[image]